# multiply different values to pandas column with combination of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-wrangling

below is the sample data, i want to multiply score column with 2,3 for every name and skill1 combination :

[image]

output:

[image]

i tried below code but its taking too much time for 400 skill1.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - specifically, never post pictures of data or code. Please do the work to write and properly format the code and examples in your question so we don't have to as we try to solve the issue. Pasting pictures also makes it so your question is not searchable.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what it is that you want to happen? It looks like you're multiplying all scores by the array [2, 3] repeated to the length of the df subset. do you want to ignore skill2?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado surely, i will format my question properly from next time, its kind of urgent. yes i we can ignore skill2, just want to multiply score with fixed list [2,3] for every combination of name and skill1.

Comment: I'd recommend doing it this time if you want an answer. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's with `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['score'] = (df
    .groupby(['name', 'skill1'])['score']
    .transform(lambda x: x.multiply([2, 3])))

df
```

Output:

```
  name skill1 skill2  score
0    a     s1     k1    1.6
1    a     s1     k2    2.1
2    a     s2     k3    1.6
3    a     s2     k4    2.1
```

P.S. I'm assuming that each `name` and `skill1` combination has exactly 2 rows, otherwise it's not really clear what should be done (the above would throw `ValueError: Lengths must be equal`)

Answer (score 0):

Like a `dplyr` way in python?

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, rep, group_by, mutate, select
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     name=rep('a', 4),
...     skill1=rep(['s1', 's2'], each=2),
...     skill2=['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'], 
...     score=rep([.8, .7], 2)
... )
>>> df
      name   skill1   skill2     score
  <object> <object> <object> <float64>
0        a       s1       k1       0.8
1        a       s1       k2       0.7
2        a       s2       k3       0.8
3        a       s2       k4       0.7

>>> df >> \
    group_by(f.name, f.skill1) >> \
    mutate(multiples=[2,3], score=f.score*f.multiples) >> \
    select(~f.multiples)

      name   skill1   skill2     score
  <object> <object> <object> <float64>
0        a       s1       k1       1.6
1        a       s1       k2       2.1
2        a       s2       k3       1.6
3        a       s2       k4       2.1

[Groups: name, skill1 (n=2)]
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.